# Obtain plot data from JPEG or png file

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a program that obtains plot data from a graph(JPEG).
Vertical axis is logarithmic.
I successfully made a program that understands horizontal and vertical axes as linear (not logarithmic), see the code below:

### [image]

```
%matplotlib inline

from PIL import Image
from scipy import *
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('fig1.jpg'))

hh = im.shape[0]
ww = im.shape[2]

imshow(im)    
print(im[100,0,:])

Col = array([255,0,0])#赤
bnd = 30

yax = linspace(0.5,2e-4,hh)
xax = linspace(1,14,ww)

for i in range(hh):
    for j in range(ww):
        im[i,j,:] = 255*(any(im[i,j,:]>Col+bnd) or any(im[i,j,:]<Col-bnd))

mapim = abs(im[:,:,0]/255-1).astype(bool)

yval = array([average(yax[mapim[:,t]]) for t in range(ww)])

rlt = interp(range(100),xax,yval)
```

I have no idea how to modify it to make it understand logarithmic axis.
Please help me.

Comment: If you're not using a more advanced image recognition, you will need to provide some ``is_logarithmic`` into to your algorithm, which then can handle the data according to the input.

Comment: I want to know the value from this graph. To use this program, if the all axis described as linearly. However, if the graph is described as logarithmic, I can not obtain the data. How can I solve ?

Comment: Map your y-axis to a linear range by calculating `log()` of the lower and the upper bound respectively - logarithm to any base will work here as long as you stay consistent throughout the program, but the axis labels suggest `log10()` - and then create your data the same way you already did. Afterwards you go the other way round and calculate `base ** y` for all the y values of your data, using the same base as you used before.

Comment: Just in case, have you checked this first? It works like a charm both online and on desktop https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert the y max and min to log scale:

```
ymax_lin = log10(0.5)
ymin_lin = log10(2e-4)

yax = linspace(ymax_lin,ymin_lin,hh)
```

and convert back to linear the `yval` values at the end:

```
yval = 10**yval
```

The full working code is here:

```
%matplotlib inline

from PIL import Image
from scipy import *
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('fig1.jpg'))

hh = im.shape[0]
ww = im.shape[1]

imshow(im)    
print(im[100,0,:])

Col = array([255,0,0])
bnd = 30


ymax_lin = log10(0.5)
ymin_lin = log10(2e-4)

yax = linspace(ymax_lin,ymin_lin,hh)
xax = linspace(1,14,ww)

for i in range(hh):
    for j in range(ww):
        im[i,j,:] = 255*(any(im[i,j,:]>Col+bnd) or any(im[i,j,:]<Col-bnd))

mapim = abs(im[:,:,0]/255-1).astype(bool)


yval = array([average(yax[mapim[:,t]]) for t in range(ww)])

yval = 10**yval

rlt = interp(range(100),xax,yval)
```